# use ls command to find some *.app files on macos

Tags: linux

There are some .app files in the folder, such as

```
   folder_A/1.app
           /2.app
           /subF/3.app
           /3.txt
```

Then i want to use ls command to check if there are any .app files under folder_A, i can use `ls -R folder_A`  to list all the files under "folder_A" and sub folder "subF", but on Macos, the app file is also considered as an directory that ls will list all the files contained in 1.app,2.app and so on.

For example, 1.app contains some .png,.txt; then `ls -R folder_A` will return all the png and txt files, not the 1.app itself. But i want to list all the app files under folder_A and its sub folder without list all the files included in .app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the right tool for the job.

```
find folder_A -name '*.app'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command is better suited for traversing a directory hierarchy.

```
find folder_A -name '*.app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Find can be easily used to search on specific files

```
find folder_name -name "*.app" -print
```

folder_name can be an absolute path or a relative path.